# Adjective followed by infinitive?

Tags: verbs, adjectives, adverbs

In English, there exists a construct which I do not quite understand.

> The monad rolled around the woods, **careful** not to fall into the river.

> The human was **careful** not to awaken the baby.

> She was **keen** to win his affections.

In fact, I am not even sure if these are actually adjectives, or adjective-looking adverbs which describe an infinitive verb.

Sed ĉi tie estas Stack Exchange por Esperanto, do mia(j) demando(j) estas...

- (0) ...kiaj vortoj estas tiuj en la kunteksto de kaŭ la angla kaŭ Esperanto
- (1) ...kiel oni dirus tian frazon en Esperanto

  - ekz ĉu la unua laŭlitere provus tradukita al io kiel "La monado ruliĝis ĉirkaŭ la arbaro, **atente** ne fali en la rivero" (laŭlitere "...carefully not falling...")

En la franca, ekzemple, la unuaj du estus "...faire attention à [ne pas faire] <qch>", mi kredas. En la angla, mi ne estas certa.

Comment: Not related to the question, but I dunno how acceptable "kaŭ" is, in comparison to "kajaŭ", "kaj/aŭ", and plain "aŭ" with context of inclusivity.

Comment: It is not: words in Esperanto are essentially never compounded by leaving out part of the root. Normally you just want _kaj/aŭ_ or just _aŭ_, as you pointed out.

Comment: You might want to edit the question to use kaj/aŭ. Mi devis vidi la komentojn por kompreni pri kio temis. Ŝajne [monado](http://vortaro.net/#monado) kaj _kaŭ_ en unu frazo estis tro multe por mi. Por demandi pri Esperanto ĉi tie, prefere uzi la esperantan (aŭ la anglan) ;).

Answer (score 2):

```
It rolled around the woods, careful not to fall into the river.
```

Tie ĉi temas pri adverbo. Tio evidentiĝas se vi movas la *careful*:

```
It carefully rolled around the woods, so as not to fall into the river.
```

Do, se ve volus tion traduki, vi povus uzi adverbon por priskribi la agon:

```
La monado singarde turniĝis en la arbaro, por ne fali en la riveron.
```

La aliaj ekzemploj:

```
The human was careful not to awaken the baby.
She was keen to win his affections.
```

Tie ĉi povus temi pri adjektivoj aŭ adverboj. En traduko, vi povus uzi ĉu adverbon:

```
La homo singarde agis (parolis, marŝis, moviĝis) por ke la bebo ne vekiĝu (aŭ: por ne veki la bebon).
```

ĉu adjektivon:

```
La homo estis singarda, por ke la bebo ne vekiĝu (aŭ: por ne veki la bebon).
```

Ekzemploj pli aŭtoritataj pri tiuj strukturoj:

```
ni kisis lin singarde, delikate, por ke li ne ploru
```

(Fundamenta Krestomatio)

```
“Ni devas esti tre singardaj, por ke, anstataŭ akceli la aferon, ni ĝin ne pereigu...
```

(Paroladoj de Zamenhof)

Comment: Rimarko, kian mi ankaŭ faris al Juha Metsäkallas:  en la unua frazo _atente_ ne akceptas *i*-komplementon, ĉar ĝi efektive nur priskribas _turniĝis_, kiel vi klarigis. Devas esti do _atentante_.

Comment: Dankon @Joffysloffy, vi pravas. Mi fakte estis forgesinta ŝanĝi lian tradukon. Mi skribis _laŭ viaj vortoj_ ĉar nek _monado_, nek _turniĝi_ estas vortoj, kiujn mi uzus en tiu traduko :), ne pro tio ke mi planis simple citi lian frazon. Mi jam korektis tion.

Comment: Nedankinde :). Mi tute komprenas.

Comment: I has unrelated question. Why the subjunctive/volitive and not present?

Comment: "U-formo montras, ke la ago aŭ stato ne estas reala, sed dezirata, volata, ordonata aŭ celata." [PMEG](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/verboj/vola.html). En tiu sama paĝo oni klarigas pri -u formo en _ke_ subfrazoj.

Answer (score 2):

> The monad rolled around the woods, careful not to fall into the river.
>
> La monado ruliĝis tra la arboj, atentanta (por ke) ne fali en la riveron.

Adjective, *careful* relates to *the monad*.

> The human was careful not to awaken the baby.
>
> La homo atentis ne veki la bebon.
>
> La homo atentis por ne veki la bebon.

Adjective too, quite clear. However *be+adjective* can be translated as *verb* in Esperanto. To stress the carefulness *por* might be injected.

> She was keen to win his affections.
>
> Ŝi deziris gajni lian amon.
>
> Ŝi estis fervora por akiri lian kor(inklin)on.

Adjective too, even more clear. In Esperanto be+adjective can become verb too.

Comment: “atentanta (por ke) ne fali”: _(por ke)_ estu _(por)_.

Comment: I agree the first *careful* is an adjective because the clause "careful not to fall into the river" is short for "**being** careful not to fall into the river". See [this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/182078/should-it-be-carefully-instead-of-careful-in-this-sentence)